# bootstrap 4 element positioning in Angular app view

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a blog template using bootstrap 4 in angular 7 application where I need to create two cards an a row, one is of the blog posts and the other card contains category. The category card is getting fetched from a different component and called using it's selector i.e `<app-blog-category></app-blog-category>` in the main HTML component. Please look at the image below for reference. Below are the problems I'm facing in the view.

1) the image inside the horizontal card is not taking the full height and width of the card

2) the second card i.e of category is getting vertically centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col col-lg-12" style="text-align:center; font-size:22px">All Blogs
      <br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="row" *ngIf="allBlogs.length>0">
      <div class="col-lg-9 card" *ngFor="let blog of allBlogs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a [routerLink]="['/blog', blog.id]">
<img src="http://localhost:4000/{{blog.imagePath}}" class="card-img-top card-img-size" alt="blog1"></a>
           </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
        <div class="card-block px-3">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{blog.title}}</h4>
          <p class="card-text">{{blog.description}}</p>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="mt-auto btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">   //note that this part is called from a separate angular component by it's selector
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 card">
                <article class="filter-group">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <header class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="title">Categories</h6>
                            </header>
                            <ul class="list-menu">
                                <li *ngFor="let category of categories" [routerLink]="['/bycategory/', category.categoryId]">{{category.categoryName}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </article>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-block {
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
    box-shadow: none;

}
.card {
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .28571429rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
    margin-top:20px;
} 

.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}


.filter-group {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.37rem
}

.card-header {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

.filter-group .card-header {
    border-bottom: 0
}

.icon-control {
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 80%
}

.list-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0
}

.list-menu a {
    color: #343a40
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color: transparent
}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the second issue. It seems ok. Could you share a live snippet?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The image is like this because it is going full width and increasing proportionally. The left gap happens because of the left padding in parent div with `col-md-4` class.
There are different ways to solve it, but I'd recommend to use a `<div>` with `background-image: url()`, `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` instead of `<img>` tag in this case, and add `height: 100%` to fit vertically. I put the CSS inline, but you can use a class.
For the padding on the left, add Bootrstrap class: `pl-0` to remove any `padding-left`;

```
<div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
  <a href = "#">
    <div class="card-img-top card-img-size" [ngStyle]="{'height': '100%', 'background-image': 'url(' + blog.imagePath + ')', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-position': 'center'}" alt="blog1"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**2)** The issue is happening because only after the last card added in the loop that the categories card is added. So, the categories card ends up next to the last card complementing the `col-9` with `col-3`.

You can wrap all center cards in a col and modifying the `.col-9` of cards to be `.col-12`. It will solve that.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="allBlogs.length>0">

  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-md-12 card" *ngFor="let blog of allBlogs">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
          <a href = "#">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-size" [ngStyle]="{'height': '100%', 'background-image': 'url(' + blog.imagePath + ')', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-position': 'center'}" alt="blog1"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
          <div class="card-block px-3">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{blog.title}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{blog.description}}</p>
            <br>
            <a href = "#" class="mt-auto btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <app-blog-category></app-blog-category>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: its not getting resolved. Here is the live snippet please have a look --- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlbxbr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Edited the answer. I used ``[ngStyle]`` for the first. For some reason, the image is not been rendering in stackblitz, but it should work in a different environment.

Comment: thanks the second issue got solved but for the first issue the image is still not getting rendered in the vew